# Install imutils within ROS

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, ros, imutils

I have an *Ubuntu 16.04 OS* with *ROS kinetic*.

When I open a terminal and type `python` it loads python 2.7, and as I try to `import imutils` it says it's not there.

Then, I tried to install it with `pip install imutils`, but it says: `requirment already satisfied in bla/bla/python3.5/bla.`

If I open the terminal and type `python3`, it loads *Python 3.5*, and when I try to import that lib, it complaints that it can't find `cv2`, and gives an address pointing to where the Python ROS package is located (*Python 2.7*).

Up to this point, it makes sense to me (I am aware of the `.bashrc` loading the ROS packages), but then, how can I install `imutils` in the Python version of ROS? I want to use the compatible `imutils` with my *ROS Kinetic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `pip` is set to *Python 3.5*.

So, you can bypass it using `pip2` instead:

```
pip2 install imutils
```

or

```
sudo pip2 install imutils
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Check your `pip` s link to Python versions assignment:

```
pip --version
pip2 --version
pip3 --version
sudo pip --version
sudo pip2 --version
sudo pip3 --version
```

Then choose the desired Python version which assigned to these `pip` or you can change the `pip` s link address ([a relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)).

Comment: Thank you @Benyamin, this makes a lot of sense. I got a problem though, when I type pip2 it throws me an error, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'. I tryed reinstalling pip2.7, that is located in the correct folder, but sends a similar error. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I found the solution, I had to reinstall pyOpenSSL, but as pip2 wouldnt work I had to use "sudo python -, easy_install --upgrade puOpenSSL" and this did the trick.

Thank you for your help!