# Ipython does not see the installed library

Tags: python, ipython

I have a working Python 3.6 and the package `imutils` is recognized, importable in its shell. Today I installed some packages on my Python 2 for another task, and now my IPython does not recognize `imutils` anymore:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b01afa4ab41d> in <module>()
      4 import random
      5 import math
----> 6 import imutils
      7 import re
      8 import time

ImportError: No module named imutils
```

What's going on? How fragile are these things, seriously.

I run `sys.executable` on both environments and the result is the same:

`/usr/bin/python3`

I checked my Python2 and the package is not installed there:

```
sudo -H pip2.7 uninstall imutils
Skipping imutils as it is not installed.
```

Doing this:

```
 /usr/bin/python3 -V
```

Returns this:

```
Python 3.6.7
```

Restarting does not work. I did use sudo commands, installed, uninstalled several times - no luck. Something has screwed up my Python, I think.

P.S: I do use Python3 on my IPython as interpreter.

P.S: I don't use Python 3.4 as a kernel whatsoever, they are all 3.6.

**EDIT:** Okay it is clear that ROS installation screwed up my Python path since I see this:

```
os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")
'/home/user/ros_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
```

**HOW CAN I SET IT BACK TO WHERE IT WAS BY DEFAULT?**

Comment: This thread has nothing to do with that one you linked @coldspeed. Read the text before taking such actions.

Comment: I read it all right. You installed this package on python3.6, but linked python3.4 as a backend to your ipython. I suggest _you_ read the post before accusing others of not reading

Comment: What Python 3.4? I don't have that even. Plus, I don't use Conda or virtualenv. The link you gave has zero useful information whatsoever.

Comment: what does `/usr/bin/python3 -V` print for you on the terminal?

Comment: Also `print(sys.path)` in both the Python 3 environment where `imutils` is importable and the Python 3 environment where `imutils` is not importable (and if you see a discrepancy, don't try to fix things by messing with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` - that's likely to break things harder).

Comment: @user2357112 Hey, that returns Python 2.7 on Ipython due to some ROS installation. Although I DO set my kernel above to 3, it keeps returning 2.7 for some reason. My Pythonpath has to be changed I think, since ROS screwed it up.

Comment: [install-imutils-within-ros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280841/install-imutils-within-ros/53289275#53289275)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the fact that ROS sourced its own Python version (2.7) by changing the `PYTHONPATH`.

Once I removed it from my .bashrc, it started to work again.

Comment: What does ROS stand for?